# Most idiomatic way to create a default struct

Tags: rust

To create a default struct, I used to see `fn new() -> Self` in Rust, but today, I discovered `Default`. So there are two ways to create a default struct:

```
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Point {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Point {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
        }
    }
}

impl Default for Point {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Point {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _p1 = Point::new();
    let _p2: Point = Default::default();
}
```

What is the better / the most idiomatic way to do so?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you *had* to pick one, implementing the `Default` trait is the better choice to allow your type to be used generically in more places while the `new` method is probably what a human trying to use your code directly would look for.

However, your question is a false dichotomy: you can do **both**, and I encourage you to do so! Of course, repeating yourself is silly, so I'd call one from the other (it doesn't really matter which way):

```
impl Point {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Default::default()
    }
}
```

[Clippy even has a lint for this exact case!](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#new_without_default)

I use `Default::default()` in structs that have member data structures where I might change out the implementation. For example, I might be currently using a `HashMap` but want to switch to a `BTreeMap`. Using `Default::default` gives me one less place to change.

---

In this particular case, you can even derive `Default`, making it very succinct:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Point {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Default::default()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _p1 = Point::new();
    let _p2: Point = Default::default();
}
```

Comment: I'd just like to point out that there's a pretty common pattern for "configuration" structs that looks like 

`let config = MyConfig { option1: 2, option2: None, .. Default::default() }`

Comment: @WesleyWiser yep! although you aren't restricted to `Default::default()` there; it can be `MyStruct::new()` or even an existing variable.

Comment: Unfortunately, `{ ..Default::default() }` doesn't work on `#[non_exhaustive]` structs