# Why is wrapping a match statement in an Ok considered bad form?

Tags: rust

In a [blog post](https://boats.gitlab.io/blog/post/why-ok-wrapping/), Rust contributor withoutboats mentions:

> Most of my functions with many return paths terminate with a `match` statement. Technically, these could be reduced to a single return path by just wrapping the whole match in an `Ok`, but I don’t know anyone who considers that good form, and I certainly don’t.

A (somewhat contrived) example of this--

bad:

```rust
Ok(match response {
    UserResponse(user) => user,
    ItemResponse(item) => item?,
})
```

better:

```rust
match response {
    UserResponse(user) => Ok(user),
    ItemResponse(item) => Ok(item?),
}
```

Why is that the case?

Comment: As far as I know this is just a personal opinion. I've written code like the first example before. Reading boats' blog post is the first time I saw any suggestion of it being "bad form".

Comment: I understand why this question was closed, but I think there is context that may give some justification for reopening it. Beyond just "is Ok-wrapping bad?", it actually is a fact-based question about what the community considers good form, which is along the same lines as asking about [idiomatic code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41510424/3650362) or [best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45086595/3650362), which we don't (always) have a problem with. And burntsushi's answer is good enough to keep around for others who might read the original article and arrive at the same question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is kind of a tricky question to answer. I personally can't recall ever seeing anyone express this opinion before. To be fair, I can't say that I've ever heard the opposite. That is, I don't remember anyone ever explicitly encouraging this sort of pattern in code.

I've certainly used this pattern before, although somewhat sparingly. To demonstrate, this typically occurs when you have a `match` expression with several cases in a tail expression that returns a `Result`, and you don't want to write `Ok` for each case. Like this:

```
Ok(match something {
    Something::Foo => 1,
    Something::Bar => 2,
    Something::Quux => fallible?,
    Something::Baz => return Err(...),
})
```

As opposed to

```
match something {
    Something::Foo => Ok(1),
    Something::Bar => Ok(2),
    Something::Quux => fallible,
    Something::Baz => Err(...),
}
```

It's not a huge difference, but if you have a lot of `Ok` cases, it can get a bit annoying. Or at least, this was the primary complaint in Boat's blog post (in defense of `Ok`-wrapping).

Another variant of this pattern is 1) when your function returns a `Result`, 2) the tail expression of the function is also a `Result`, 3) the error types are not the same and 4) the error type in (1) has a `From` impl for the error type in (2). That is, instead of writing

```
something.fallible().map_err(From::from)
```

one can write

```
Ok(something.fallible()?)
```

`?` is so ubiquitous that I've always kind of chalked up the difference between these to personal style.

I can't possibly know what the blog author had in mind when saying that this was poor form. My guess---and I somewhat share this---is that there is a lack of symmetry between the arms of the `match` expression. Some of them are effectively early returns while others aren't early returns at all. I could see how some might consider that jarring.

Otherwise, I do occasionally use both of these patterns, but not religiously so. If it comes up and it makes sense, then I don't have too much of a problem with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was a new idea for me, too. I've used `Ok(match{})` in my code, and definitely use `Ok(fallible()?)` a ton, and couldn't see any problems with it. My hunch was that it was about being explicit in each match arm, but mainly I asked because the opinion was so vehement.